# Rotate image to have the MRZ code at the bottom - Python

Tags: python, rotation

I'm new to python and am wanting to automatically rotate an image so the machine-readable zone (MRZ) is at the bottom of the screen.  I am using passporteye to read the image and unless it's the correct way I get errors.

[Original image passed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8Ib.jpg)

[Desired rotated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBmeR.jpg)

Referred to the following but was not able to develop a solution

1. https://github.com/farhanchoudhary/PAN_Card_OCR_Project
2. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/
3. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/656/how-to-retrieve-machine-readable-zones-from-a-passport-image-with-python-using-the-passporteye-library

Comment: Your two images look the same to me.

Comment: @fmw42, sorry I've updated the pictures.

Comment: Perhaps get the outer contour of the two pages and rotate so that the long dimension of each page is horizontal.